# How to create a real time app using XSockets?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, real-time, xsockets.net

I am currently learning about Xsockets in MVC and it would really help me if someone could help me with this. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and .NET 4.5. Although, I've found many documentations, I was unable to find any implementations to refer from. What would really save my life is a step by step guide to create any real time app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to take a look at signalr instead of xsockets. Especially if you can use the new aspnetcore

I am one of the developers behind xsockets, so take my recommendation serious :)

Comment: I have already worked with SignalR @Uffe. Just wanted some insight into XSockets thats all. And I could not find any signalR documentations for video calling using WebRTC so, was just curious. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, then I understand your question. Did not realise that it was WebRTC you were implementing. The XSockets webrtc stuff is very old and I am sure that there are other solution out there today. Sorry for not being able to help out.

Comment: It would really help me if you could point me in the right direction with XSockets, just basic real time stuff nothing much. Thanks!